# Rails - Display message on Show page based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a marketplace app where sellers list items to sell. I expire listings 30 days after they've last been updated using the code below.

in listing model:

```
def self.not_expired
   where('created_at >= ?', Date.current - 30.day)
end
```

In controller:

```
def index
   @listings = Listing.not_expired
end
```

The above lets me filter the index pages with listings that have not expired yet. How do I show a message on the show pages on these expired listings? If an expired listing shows up in a google search, when users click to the page, I want a message saying the listing has expired.

I'm looking for some conditional statement to put into either my controller or the show html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to make an instance method of the class method you have already:

```
def expired?
  self.created_at <= 30.days.ago
end
```

Then in your ERB:

```
<% if @listing.expired? %>
  Message indicating the listing has expired
<% else %>
  The listing
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
# Listing model
def expired?
  self.created_at <= 30.days.ago
end

# ListingsController
def show
  @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
end

# listings/show.html.haml
- if @listing.expired?
  = "This listing is expired!"
- else
  # your logic to display a non-expired listing
```

---

Also, I recommend you to use a constant for the number of days before the listing goes expired. It would be easier to change it in your code later.

Something like this would work:

```
# Listing model
DAYS_BEFORE_EXPIRED = 30

def expired?
  self.created_at <= DAYS_BEFORE_EXPIRED.days.ago
end

def self.not_expired
  where('created_at >= ?', DAYS_BEFORE_EXPIRED.days.ago)
end
```

Comment: Isn't `expired?` going to return true here until the listing actually expires, and false thereafter? Or am I misunderstanding the logic?

Comment: I already have the not_expired method. Just so I understand, why can't I use `if @listing.not_expired?` instead of creating a new method as you suggest?

Comment: If you refer to the class method `not_expired`, then it is a Class method, not an instance method. You need an instance method to test if the instance's `created_at` value is expired or not. --- If you have defined the instance method `.not_expired?`, then you can use it.

Comment: @pjmorse `30.days.ago` will return a date like `26 Jul 2014`. We want to test if a record was created *after* this `26 Jul 2014` => `created_at >= '26 Jul 2014'`

Comment: Right, but if the `created_at` date is *after* (i.e. `>=`) `30.days.ago` isn't the listing *not* expired, by OP's definition? So `expired?` should return false?

Comment: @pjmorse Oh you are right! Thank you for pointing that out, and sorry for my blindness

Comment: If the listing was created in the last 30 days, I want to show it i.e. not expired.

Comment: Using constants like this in place of magic numbers is definitely a practice to encourage.